# Getting Error: Error at line 18/11: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been getting the following error:    "Error at line 18/11: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" with my code and am unsure what is causing it.

```
SELECT my_records.my_date, h.reviewed_date, count(case when my_records.reviewed = 'Y' then 1 else null end), count(case when my_records.approved = 'Y' then 1 else null end), count(case when my_records.approved = 'N' then 1 else null end) as from 
(select h.id, 
  case 
    when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Monthly' then
      to_char(h.reviewed_date, 'Month') 
    when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Daily' then
      to_char(h.reviewed_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Weekly' then
      to_char(TRUNC(h.reviewed_date, 'IW'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  end as my_date,  
    case 
    when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Monthly' then
      TRUNC(date_sys, 'MM') 
    when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Daily' then
      TRUNC(date_sys) 
    when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Weekly' then
      TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW')
  end as h.reviewed_date,
  h.reviewed, h.approved
FROM INGESTED i
LEFT OUTER JOIN highlighted h
ON i.id = h.id_ingested 
WHERE h.reviewed_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P43_START_DATE) AND TO_DATE(:P43_END_DATE)
) my_records
GROUP BY my_date, h.reviewed_date
```

Comment: Missing column alias. `...end) as from (select h.id,...`

Comment: BTW, your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. Move the h.reviewed_date condition(s) from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is formatting the query so that you understand it's structure.

```
SELECT 
    my_records.my_date, h.reviewed_date, 
    count(
        case when my_records.reviewed = 'Y' then 
            1 
        else 
            null 
        end), 
    count(
        case when my_records.approved = 'Y' then 
            1 
        else 
            null 
        end), 
    count(
        case when my_records.approved = 'N' then 
            1 
        else 
            null 
        end) as 
from 
    (select h.id, 
      case 
        when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Monthly' then
          to_char(h.reviewed_date, 'Month') 
        when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Daily' then
          to_char(h.reviewed_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
        when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Weekly' then
          to_char(TRUNC(h.reviewed_date, 'IW'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
      end as my_date,  
        case 
        when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Monthly' then
          TRUNC(date_sys, 'MM') 
        when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Daily' then
          TRUNC(date_sys) 
        when :P43_DATE_RANGES = 'Weekly' then
          TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW')
      end as h.reviewed_date,
      h.reviewed, h.approved
    FROM INGESTED i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN highlighted h
    ON i.id = h.id_ingested 
    WHERE h.reviewed_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P43_START_DATE) AND TO_DATE(:P43_END_DATE)
    ) my_records
GROUP BY my_date, h.reviewed_date
```

As you can see, the last `count` if followed by `as`, which is normally used to provide an alias, but is followed by `from`; And that is causing the error.

Provide an alias after the `as` or remove the `as`.